# Rewrite a T-SQL query containing subqueries to using joins

Tags: sql-server, database, t-sql, join, subquery

I need to select a column from the Application table in the main outer query, which means I have to rewrite the following query to use joins rather than subqueries in order to move the Application table into the scope of the main outer query.

```
SELECT XMLValue
FROM DynamicField
WHERE ParentID IN (
   SELECT DynamicFieldID
   FROM DynamicField
   WHERE ParentID IN (
      SELECT DynamicFieldID
      FROM Application
      )
   )
```

Does anyone have a suggestion on how to solve this?

Comment: Can you add sample data, for each of the tables, and expected output.  The FAQ has a great guide on [producing sample data](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) if you need a little help.

Comment: Rather than using joins you may want to look into WHERE EXISTS. I do not think joins will do the trick as this may return multiple rows.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So something like this:

```
SELECT s.*
FROM DynamicField t
INNER JOIN DynamicField t1 on(t.parentID = t1.DynamicFieldID)
INNER JOIN Application s ON(t1.parentID = s.DynamicFieldID)
```

This will select all from Application table.

Answer (score 1):

If we don't include result set from a table, we better put it in the where exists portion and NOT to include in the joins.

```
SELECT XMLValue, app.[your application column name]
FROM DynamicField mainouter
join application app on exists(
    select 1  from  DynamicField appfriend
    where app.DynamicFieldID = appfriend.ParentID
    and appfriend..DynamicFieldID = mainouter.parentID
    )
```

Comment: Although this solution provided the same result as the one @Yossi suggested, it took about ten times as long to execute (the query in question is a small part of a more extensive one).